# xticklabels not disappearing even after setting them to null

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot things from 0.01 to 0.1 on a log scale. I am using the following piece of code:

```
    fig = plt.figure   ( figsize=(4/1.6,3/1.6), constrained_layout=True )
    ax  = plt.axes()`
    plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
    ax.tick_params(direction='in', bottom=True, top=True, left=True, right=True, which='both')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
    ax.plot (x_data, y_data)
    ax.minorticks_off()
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    yticks = np.arange(0.985, 1.005, 0.005)
    ax.set_yticks ( yticks )
    ax.set_yticklabels (ax.get_yticks(), weight='bold')`
    ax.set_ylim   ( 0.985, 1.0 )
    ax.set_xlim   ( 0.01, 0.1 )
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.AutoMinorLocator())
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:1.3f}') )
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:1.2f}') )
    ax.set_aspect ('auto')
```

As I am doing this, I am still getting the labels of minorticks on the x-axis. This is what I am seeing:
[image]

My question is, why am I seeing all this extraneous stuff on the xtick labels? I have tried turning `ax.set_xticklabels([])` at the very top and inserting labels manually, but it still did not work. **What am I doing wrong here?**

*My desired output is for xticklabels to be bold and be "0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1".*

Comment: For such a small range the minor ticks are labelled.

Answer (score 0):

One way to just keep the ticks you want would be to use `ax.set_ticks()` and `ax.set_ticklabels()` to what you want and then switch off minor ticks. I have updated your code below. Do note that I added some rotation, horizontal alignment for the xticks and increased the decimal places from 2 to 3 for the xticks. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4/1.6,3/1.6), constrained_layout=True )
ax  = plt.axes()
plt.rcParams["axes.labelweight"] = "bold"
ax.tick_params(direction='in', bottom=True, top=True, left=True, right=True, which='both')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
y_data=[1,0.999,0.997,0.993,0.985]
x_data=[0.01, 0.02,0.05,0.09,0.1]
ax.plot (x_data, y_data)
ax.set_xscale('log')
yticks = np.arange(0.985, 1.005, 0.005)
ax.set_yticks ( yticks )
ax.set_yticklabels (ax.get_yticks(), weight='bold')
ax.set_ylim   ( 0.985, 1.0 )
ax.set_xlim   ( 0.01, 0.1 )

## New code here
ax.set_xticks([0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1])
ax.set_xticklabels([0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1], weight = 'bold', rotation = 45, ha="right")
ax.minorticks_off()

import matplotlib.ticker as tck
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.StrMethodFormatter('{x:1.3f}') )
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.StrMethodFormatter('{x:1.3f}') )
ax.set_aspect ('auto')
```

**Output plot**

[image]